# Deep linking from Button click, doesn't take me to the app

Tags: android, deep-linking

[image]
I have implemented deep linking in my android app. I receive an email and it contains, a reset button and a link. Click on the link provide the option to choose my app. But click on Reset your password button, takes me to browser by default. I have checked the link in the browser after clicking the button.

**From Button click**
https://example.com/password/reset/confirm/ZDAxODUxY2YtYTBjNi00MzQ3LWE0YzctZjIzYWVjNzY3ZjA0/aoqt2u-d5d10b417fdb1db9e622f2fe17816ff2?utm_medium=email&_hsmi=116282858&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-8NrUE8bP7llnuObzZEIkK3X2Gq03cHsvf2c6g78DPoLVn7emLLUJrNdxIE3UvVAzQM74OKME6qDrIdoZU34BvOUswGIQ&utm_content=116282858&utm_source=hs_email

**the link in the email**
https://example.com/password/reset/confirm/ZDAxODUxY2YtYTBjNi00MzQ3LWE0YzctZjIzYWVjNzY3ZjA0/aoqt2u-d5d10b417fdb1db9e622f2fe17816ff2

I have the below in my manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.resetpassword.ResetPasswordActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
            android:theme="@style/AppSplashTheme">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I don't know, why button click not works.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you confirm your default apps and other device configurations? If you have selected "always use X", then it is supposed to override the apps deep links.

Comment: @Bonatti Yes, making "always use" works. But I can't force the user to make that choice. Is there any work around for this to always take to my app, without user knowing that.

Comment: What I meant is, if the user has previously selected "Always Use X", then the OS will always use X, if you, while testing has selected that, then its the expected behavior. Try to clear this selection, and see if its working as intended. AFAIK, in a previous project I have used, I also had to use regex on each path/URI my app was using in the manifest, because I had some dynamic links. Since your action is broad (View Intent), then you are telling the OS: "Hey, my app is able to resolve that intent", together all other available options.